# Algorithm for specific 1-bit bitmap coordinate conversion

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, coordinates

I know Stack Overflow is a populated place and so I will try to make myself brief. I am a hobbyist programmer working within a small pocket niche of the coding world; my experience outside is horribly limited.

My dilemma is this: I have a 1-bit 2D matrix consisting of arbitrary data intended to represent on/off pixels on the screen. Consider an example for the imagination:

```
11110111101111111100
10111111111111111111
11011111111111011111
11111010111111111111
11111111011111111111
11111111111100011111
11111011011110001101
```

This is truly a poor example for my exact purposes, but it serves the question O.K. As a programmer, I look at this image matrix of data and consider ways to losslessly compress this, perhaps into a smaller, 1D matrix. I realize that large portions of the elements defining "on" pixels (this distinction is rather arbitrary, a display of 'on' pixels turned 'off' to create an image is the same as a display of 'off' pixels turned 'on' to create the same image) may be recognized by one's mind's eye as being solid rectangles of "on" pixels. Consider:

```
11110111101111111100
10111111111111111111
11011111111111011111
xxxxx010111111111111
xxxxx111011111111111
xxxxx111111100011111
xxxxx011011110001101
```

Storing the coordinates of a rectangle defining a rectangular section of elements of "on" pixels (and then storing those coordinates sequentially in a 1D array) seems like the best approach to this issue, for later, to redraw the same image, I may just scan through the resulting 1D array and plot all of the rectangles.

My question is: **Does there exist a method or algorithm for performing this specific kind of conversion, and that, most efficiently?** For that, consider Bresenham's Line Algorithm, which is arguably the most efficient at what it does, and many other algorithms out there.

I in my ignorance beyond my niche would like to assume that there existed a plethora of small algorithmic challenges like these, solved decades ago by mad computer scientists who nowadays surround themselves with magnetic tape and vacuum tubes. This seems to be the case for a lot of algorithmic hurdles like these which I often run into, that is, they were solved way before my time.

Comment: You don't say how large your matrix is, but if the individual rows are long and you have long runs of 1's or 0's, you should consider run-length encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Image compresion is never exact. The level of compression depends a lot on the image itself. So, even you cleverly "discover" a new algorithm, it will succeed sometimes, where other times it will do a poor job.

This is due to some random factor in the nature of each image.

There's an old but still valid site with value info: [CFAQ](https://www.maximumcompression.com/compression_faq/compfaq_part1.php)

About your "rectangle" algorithm, there's something near to it: [PCIF algorithm](http://www.researchandtechnology.net/pcif/algorithm_polyomino_compression.php)

Comment: Yes, some compressions are never always exact, but there are lossless ones. The PCIF algorithm page seems loosely worded, the general idea as it was laid out seems understandable, though I suspect I'll have to read further into the suggested documentation to really grasp it. Looks 'a promising approach, thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of lossless image compression algorithms, perhaps the best known being PNG. There's also RLE, which works surprisingly well.

Comment: @JimMischel hmm just tried RLE on this and the result is worse than raw sequence ... may be using background color and represent only the non background pixels only (if there count is significantly lower. looks like there is less zeros ...) will be better. but I suspect entropy encoding (like Huffman) will be even better for this also GIF lharc will do